# More efficient and effective queryset?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have this models in my project:

```py
...
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    income = models.BigIntegerField()
    ...

class Credit(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cycle = models.CharField(choices=CYCLE_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    amount = models.BigIntegerField()
    ...
```

I want a queryset that queries the database for a user whose income is greater than `$10,000`, and who has **at least two(2)** credits whose `cycle` is `cycle_credited` and amount is `$30,000`.

Currently, I have the following querysets:

```py
...
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)

is_eligible = False

num_of_ten_k_credits = Credit.objects.filter(user=user, user__income__gt=10000, cycle=constants.cycle_credited, amount=30000).count()

if num_of_ten_k_credits >= 2:
    is_eligible = True
```

Is there a more efficient and effective way to do this? Like a one-liner solution with fewer DB calls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can optimize and make it more readable by adding a few changes to your existing codebase. For example add related_name to your `Credit` model class

```
lass Credit(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="credits")
    cycle = models.CharField(choices=CYCLE_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    amount = models.BigIntegerField()
    ...
```

Now this is how you can achieve the desired result using more optimized and readable code

1. If you are inside views  having request with user

```
num_of_ten_k_credits = request.user.credits.filter(income__gt=10000,
                                             cycle=constants.cycle_credited,
                                             amount=30000,
                                             )

if num_of_ten_k_credits >= 2:
    is_eligible = True
```

2. If you are not in views and do not have `request.user` then do it this way

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)

num_of_ten_k_credits = user.credits.filter(income__gt=10000,
                                             cycle=constants.cycle_credited,
                                             amount=30000,
                                             )

if num_of_ten_k_credits >= 2:
    is_eligible = True
```

In both ways I tried to avoid `__` that is in nature joins and make queries slow.

Comment: What about if the model is rigid that appending `related_name` will break a lot of other aspects of the codebase? Can `loan_set` be used instead of `credits`? Also, no `.count()` needed?

Comment: Did you take into consideration that `income` is not a field in `Credit`? It's a field in `User`.